# The feeling you get/the feeling when

Tags: phrase-usage, colloquial-language

1. **The feeling you get** when your students get good grades is out of this world.
2. **The feeling** when your students get good grades is out of this world.

I'm confused between 'the feeling you get' and 'the feeling.' Please let me know which one's correct.

Comment: What do you think Ashraf? Which one would you choose?

Comment: To be hones both sound good to me specially when I translate it to my language (which is obviously not a good way to learn a language). I'd say 1 is a bit more empathetic.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is clear and grammatical.

Although the reference is to **you get**, one understands that the individual is either speaking personally or talking more generally about the feeling that teachers get in this situation.

The second sentence is looser and typical of informal conversations. Although many people speak this way and it would be understood, it is not formally correct.

The difference is that the person who gets the feeling is not specified. One presumes that it is the teacher but it could well be the students. To be correct, you need to say who gets this feeling, whether **I, you, one or some particular person**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was an IELTS question. The question was "Would you like to be a teacher?" So 'who get's the feeling' was already clear from the context. I guess I should say "The feeling you get..." since it's formal.